# Use awk to replace lines containing pattern "fin(fname)"

Tags: regex, awk

How could I use awk to replace lines containing

```
    ifstream fin(fname);
```

to

```
    ifstream fin(fname.c_str());
```

I've tried the following awk, but it did not work.

```
    /fin?fname?/ {
       sub(/fname/, "fname.c_str()", $0)
    }
    {
      print
    }
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean?  "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to the following (tested):

```
awk '/fin\(fname\)/ {sub("fname", "fname.c_str()", $0)} {print}' input_filename
```

In awk's regex matching, the parentheses `(` and `)` must be escaped with `\`

Additionally, I think you might be confusing the use of `?`: It means different things between [Regular Expression vs. Globbing](http://jazimmer.com/tclbook/select/Html/7.3.html)

- In regex, `?` means "the preceding character is optional". For example `abc?` matches both `ab` and `abc`
- In globbing, `?` means "any ONE character". Its regex equivalent is `.`

Answer (score 1):

Used sed instead:

```
sed 's/fin(fname)/fin(fname.c_str())/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> echo "ifstream fin(fname);" | awk '/ifstream fin\(fname\)/{gsub(/fname/,"fname.c_str()")}1'
ifstream fin(fname.c_str());
```